# How to manage cookies with UIWebView in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, swift, webview

What about have a topic where people can easily see how to manage cookies in a webview using the new language Swift? If you check in internet you won't find anything interesting when you need to implement this. Even the documentation by apple is poor.

Do anybody know how to handle these process in Swift? This is what I found but in Obj-C:

**SEE COOKIES STORED**

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {
NSLog(@"%@", cookie);
}
```

**DELETE STORED COOKIES**

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [storage cookies]) {
[storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

It would be nice for everybody if we can give for one time an answer to this!
Cheers!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this code:

**SEE COOKIES STORED**

```
    if let cookies = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies {
        for cookie in cookies {
            NSLog("\(cookie)")
        }
    }
```

**DELETE STORED COOKIES**

```
    var storage : NSHTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    for cookie in storage.cookies  as! [NSHTTPCookie]{
        storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
```

**swift 2.0**

```
let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
for cookie in storage.cookies! {
 storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
    for cookie in cookies {
        NSLog("\(cookie)")
    }
}

let storage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
for cookie in storage.cookies! {
    storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
```

Comment: Hi! Te method to see cookies works great! Thank you :) A lot of people will appreciate this ;-) 
The one to delete cookies doesn't.. 
storage.deleteCookie(cookie) causes an error: "Cannot convert the expression's type AnyObject to type NSHTTPCookie -> Void

Comment: I didn't check that code I just converted it into swift.now let me check this.:)

Comment: What does the last call to `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` do?

Answer (score 8):

## swift 3 clear version

**Save cookies**

```
func saveCookies() {
    guard let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies else {
        return
    }
    let array = cookies.flatMap { (cookie) -> [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]? in
        cookie.properties
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "cookies")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

**Load cookies** :

```
func loadCookies() {
    guard let cookies = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "cookies") as? [[HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]] else {
        return
    }
    cookies.forEach { (cookie) in
        guard let cookie = HTTPCookie.init(properties: cookie) else {
            return
        }
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
    }
}
```

You can call these functions like the following code

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    loadCookies()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    saveCookies()
}
```

Do not forget to have a delegate of your WebView for *webViewDidStartLoad* and *webViewDidFinishLoad*

Comment: Just a heads up that as of iOS 10 SDK Apple advises against calling synchronize: " this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Comment: can someone edit the answer to include a demo for webViewDidStartLoad ? newbie here

Answer (score 5):

**swift 2.0**

```
let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
for cookie in storage.cookies! {
 storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: What `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()` is for?

Comment: It is no longer necessary according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults "func synchronize() -> Bool" "Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."

Saying that, I have seen it used in `applicationDidEnterBackground` to make sure values are synced as the app enters the background.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the swift "translation"... Just needed to change the deletion to as! to force downcast:

```
var storage : NSHTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
for cookie in storage.cookies  as! [NSHTTPCookie]
{
    storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete answer with how to capture cookies with UIWebView's delegate function:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
        for cookie in cookies {
            print("cookie= \(cookie)")
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that cookies will saved as default and this delegate function calls every movement that finished with webview load. (It's also updated with **Swift 3.0.1**)

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on **swift 4**  then this code will disable **cookies** and also **remove the URL cache**.

```
let cookieJar : HTTPCookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! as [HTTPCookie]{
    NSLog("cookie.domain = %@", cookie.domain)
     cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
}

URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses() 
URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0 
URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**swift 3**

```
    let storage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared

    for cookie in storage.cookies! {
        storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Logout for api VKontakte, swift 3+

```
let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
dataStore.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { (records) in
    for record in records {
        if record.displayName.contains("facebook") {
            dataStore.removeData(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(), for: [record], completionHandler: {
                print("Deleted: " + record.displayName);
            })
        }
    }
}
```