# Disable Cookies UIWebView Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have already built OAuth with Social Networks using a UIWebView tho I would want user to login each time he tries to login. I would want to know how can I disable or delete cache and cookies loading in UIWebView Swift iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543817/how-to-manage-cookies-with-uiwebview-in-swift)

```
let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
for cookie in storage.cookies! {
 storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: Thanks! Just slightly changed the position of synchronize() method and It worked.

Comment: Wellcome :) @Edwards