# HTML5 Geolocation for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, html, uiwebview, geolocation

I have an HTML5/jquery-mobile application for cross-platform support. I have Android with WebView and iOS with UIWebView that points to my site. I require geolocation services and while you can pass the device permission from Android to web-app using WebView ChromeClient.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback){
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
});
```

There is no such thing in iOS. Every time I use the application I get two permission request dialogs from the iOS app and the web-app. I don't use phonegap/cordova and have no need for them. This problem has stumped me for weeks and everyone else who has this problem uses phonegap/cordova.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    // geolocation logic
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Me too have the same problem. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: I actually ended up using the ios geolocation services provided by the device and sent the coords to my javascript through the UIWebview

Comment: But in my case, I am embedding third party website in my webview. any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately on iOS I don't think that's something you can control. If you haven't already I would suggest you post a new question for this. I was able to control the web-side and the app-side in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid that alert in UIWebView AFAIK. You could use iOS location API to get current location and pass it to the webpage. Many ways to do this:

- UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.iosLocation = 43.3,-79.9"), on the page can check the UA to see if this it should expect this to be set, or it could wait for 1-2 seconds after load complete and if this prop is not set, then use HTML5 geo. You would inject this on UIWebViewDelegate.webViewDidFinishLoad
- have your page try call back to iOS native code, although this far more complicated than above (requires js injection/overrides on page load)
- Set a cookie for your domain on app start that contains the location, then try read the cookie on the page, see here on how to set a cookie: [How to manage cookies with UIWebView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543817/how-to-manage-cookies-with-uiwebview-in-swift)

Comment: I've been looking at the first method, how easy would that be to implement?

Comment: Also, I've changed to WKWebView. Is the functionality the same?

Comment: set the UIWebView instance delegate to a class instance like: 
`class MyDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate {
func webViewDidFinishLoad(wv: UIWebView) {
 // do core location query to grab location
 // then inject using js into web view
}
}`

Comment: I think there is a similar function for wkwebview in objective-c which is what I'm using

Comment: Do you know how to do this with wkwebview in objective-c?